# ExtJS deselect a row by pressing on the background

Tags: extjs, grid, row

How can I deselect a selected row from a grid by pressing on the background? It seems that after I select a row I cannot deselect it I can only change my selection by selecting other rows. In windows you can deselect by pressing on the white background. Is there a way to achieve that with ExtJS grids?

EDIT: I do NOT want to do this programmatically. Please do not suggest deselectAll() and other such methods. I'm looking for a config or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `allowDeselect` config of selection model,Have a look : [Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-cfg-allowDeselect)

```
 selModel : Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel',{
            allowDeselect:true,
            mode:'SINGLE'
        }),
```

Comment: That's probably what I'm looking. I'd prefer if it was like it is on windows (click on the white space to deselect instead of clicking on the same object to deselect) since it is more natural that way but still it is something. Thanks